# threejs: How the Unit of Measure of represent for position?

Tags: three.js

If the mesh is moving from position (0,0,0) to (10,0,0). The new position of the mesh in x direction is "10". So, what will be the UOM of position. will it be in meter or millimeter or centimeter.

i.e. 10 m or 10 mm or 10 cm or 10 px ?

Comment: whatever you want it to be. there are no units in three.js. just have to be consistent with what the units mean for your application.

Comment: Thank you @gaitat! 

I want to convert the value into "meter". Do you have any clue on conversion factor? 

i.e. 10 to XX meter

Comment: as I said there are no units in three.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official answer is that ThreeJS uses SI units.  Thus distances are in meters:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6259

Comment: But this only abstract. A unit in Three can be anything you want: 1 unit can mean 1 foot, it can mean 1 meter, it can mean 1 inch, etc. It's up to you. If you want to associate physical units with physical screen pixels in Three.js, that's also up to you (something I'm working on at the moment...).

Comment: That is not completely true.

FBX have units.  STEP files have units.  Collada files have units.

Also any physical simulation requires units to have meaning, and SI units makes the most sense.

You can deviate from this, but it is highly not recommended unless you really know what you are doing.